# Error Retrieving when saving or retrieving a BD SQL Server image

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, image

When saving an image to the SQL Server 2014 database, is saved in a column of type `Image`. The problem is that when retrieving the image and receive it in a variable type `byte[]` doing the right conversion I can not see in the control intended, I have identified that when sending it to the database the number of bytes is 139551 bytes, but when retrieving it from the database, the number of bytes is 13 bytes [13]. Obviously could not change the column type to `varbinary (MAX)` because it only supports 8000 bytes...

Database recovery:

```
DataTable Tabla = ConsultasMasivasN.ConsultarSoporteIndicadorN(CodigoGI, UsuarioS);
ViewState["TblSoporte"] = Tabla;
gridListado.DataSource = Tabla;
gridListado.DataBind();

Session["Consulta"] = Tabla;
```

Handler file:

```
if (context.Session["Consulta"] != null)
{
    DataTable tbRegistro = (DataTable)context.Session["Consulta"];
    DataRow drRegistro = tbRegistro.Select(string.Format("Codigo={0}", context.Request.QueryString["Codigo"]))[0];
    byte[] imagen = (byte[])drRegistro["Soporte"];
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imagen, 0, imagen.Length);
}
```

I appreciate your help !

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `varbinary(max)` instead (and it supports **2 billion bytes** (2 GB) of size - **NOT** only 8000 bytes! [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, Change the data type in the Database Image field to **varbinary(MAX)** and use a stored procedure defining **SqlDbType.VarBinary** to insert the image into the database so I did not lose bytes in the process, before I just saved The variable type [] byte in the Image field.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SoporteIndicador](
    [Codigo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CodigoIM] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CodigoGI] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Soporte] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [NombreSoporte] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [UsuarioRegistro] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FechRegistro] [datetime] NOT NULL
```

**Error:**

```
public static int RegistrarSoporteIndicador(SoporteIndicador soporteIndicador)
        {
            int Ingreso = 0;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = Conexion.ObtenerConexion())
            {
                SqlCommand Ingresar = new SqlCommand(string.Format(
                    "Insert Into SoporteIndicador (CodigoIM,CodigoGI,Soporte,NombreSoporte,UsuarioRegistro,FechRegistro) values ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}')",
                soporteIndicador.CodigoIM,
                soporteIndicador.CodigoGI,
                soporteIndicador.Soporte, //Type []byte                soporteIndicador.NombreSoporte,
                soporteIndicador.UsuarioRegistro,
                soporteIndicador.FechRegistro), conexion);
                Ingreso = Ingresar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conexion.Close();
            }
            SqlConnection cerrarcon = Conexion.CerrarConexion();
            return Ingreso;
        }
```

**Solved:**

```
public static int RegistrarSoporteIndicador(SoporteIndicador soporteIndicador)
        {
            int Ingreso = 0;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = Conexion.ObtenerConexion())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PA_Guardar_Registro", conexion))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CodigoIM", soporteIndicador.CodigoIM);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CodigoGI", soporteIndicador.CodigoGI);
                    SqlParameter imageParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Soporte", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary);
                    imageParam.Value = soporteIndicador.Soporte;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("NombreSoporte", soporteIndicador.NombreSoporte);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UsuarioRegistro", soporteIndicador.UsuarioRegistro);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FechRegistro", soporteIndicador.FechRegistro);


                    Ingreso = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conexion.Close();
                }
            }
            SqlConnection cerrarcon = Conexion.CerrarConexion();
            return Ingreso;
        }
```